# Magento: where do I find this setting?

Tags: magento

This is the code:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/cart/revocationurl');
```

Where can I set this except in the database directly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you upload system.xml file of this module in the question (namespace/modulename/etc/system.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Magento keep all core config data on core_config_data table.
you can change it on phpmyadmin or if you use mysql cmd.

UPDATE core_config_data
SET value='anything you want'
WHERE path='checkout/cart/revocationurl';

you can learn more from this link http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-programmatically-change-magentos-core-config-data/